# ASP.NET - Dynamic ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have an ASP.NET page that has dynamically created LinkButton elements. Please note that these LinkButton elements are not added to a DataGrid, GridView, or Repeater.

When a user clicks on one of these LinkButton elements, I want to display a dialog box. To accomplish this, I was attempting to use a ModalPopupExtender and set its TargetControlID when a user clicked one of the LinkButton elements. Unfortunately this is not working.

Does anyone know how I can use the same ModalPopupExtender with multiple LinkButton elements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it thusly:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doPopUp()" Text="SomeLinkButton Lookalike" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="someHiddenButton" CssClass="hidden" />
```

then javascript:

```
function doPopUp(){
    var somehiddenbutton = 
        document.getElementById('<%= someHiddenButton.ClientID %>');
        somehiddenbutton.click();
}
```

Then you can simply have a runat server linkbutton with CSS property display:none, and that will be your TargetControlID for your ModalPopupExtender.

Hope this helps,
JP

EDIT:  I didn't include the .click() method.  ***dunce moment***

Answer (score 1):

If you can post a bit of code then it will surely help. For now I can suggest to have a hidden button as TargetControl and then use the Show method of the ModalPopUp to display it on link button click.